# Cannot Navigate to 'IF'

Tags: c#, sql, c#-3.0, windows-forms-designer

I am using this code to add and edit the employee. First I am checking via validation and next adding an image to the database and if U edit in run time means the error "**Cannot Navigate to 'IF'**" is showing. Is there any problem in coding?

```
private void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (employeevalidate() == true)
    {
        toproperties();
        if (cpbempadd.employeesave(cpemp) == true)
        {
            if (saveImageInDataBase(cpemp.Empid) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Employee Details are Saved Sucessfully....");
                grid();
                pnl_addedit.Visible = false;
                pnl_grid.Visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in Saving Employee Details... ");
    }
}
```

Validation Coding is :

```
public  bool employeevalidate()
{
    if (cpbempadd.textboxnull(txt_empid) == false) { return false; }
    if (cpbempadd.textboxnull(txt_empname) == false) { return false; }
    if (cpbempadd.textboxnull(txt_mobno) == false) { return false; }
    if (cpbempadd.textboxnull(txt_proofdetails) == false) { return false; }
    if (cpbempadd.textboxnull(txt_upload) == false) { return false; }
    if (txt_add2.Text == string.Empty) { txt_add2.Text = "-"; }
    if (txt_add3.Text == string.Empty) { txt_add3.Text = "-"; }
    if (txt_bg.Text == string.Empty) { txt_bg.Text = "-"; }
    if (txt_email.Text == string.Empty) { txt_email.Text = "-"; }
    if (txt_pf.Text == string.Empty) { txt_pf.Text = "-"; }
    if (txt_status.Text == string.Empty) { txt_status.Text = "-"; }
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting the error, and what is the actual error message you are receiving?

Comment: @DarrenYoung if i run the coding means there is no error and if i click submit button after editing nothing takes place , so i inserted a break point in this function and complied the program it's showing error in first line itself as Cannot Navigate to 'IF' and does not moves to next line..

Comment: Have you put break points inside the button submit method?  Does it reach there?  Put a break point on the first if statement and then press F11 when it breaks there.  Does that then enter the employeevalidate method?

Comment: @DarrenYoung no it does not enters to the employeevalidate() function and if i again press the F11 button.. It shows the error.

Comment: Where is the validateemployee method?  Is it in the same class as the button click method?  Or is it in the cpbempadd class (whatever that is)?

Comment: @DarrenYoung s s both are present in form itself...

Comment: From what you are saying and showing I cannot see a reason why this does not work.  Is it hitting the break point in the button click?  What is the exact message you are receiving?  Can you paste it in?

Comment: sure... http://s16.postimage.org/wmqq7q7jp/Untitled.jpg

Comment: Sorry I cannot help with this without debugging it.  I've had a quick Google and there's very little information on this.  There are a few similar issues if you do a search for 'Cannot navigate to definition', one of those responses may help.

Comment: @DarrenYoung Thanks a lot.. the problem has been solved the mistake was in Sql Query ..

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Has Been Solved.. The Mistake Was in SQL Syntax. Thanks a lot